# Is there a way to check if AWS lambda is running from java code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There is a Lambda say my Lambda Name is - XYZ which has a s3 file upload trigger. Now lets say if I upload multiple files say around 100 and the lambda execution starts.
Is there any way I can track if the lambda is running or has processed all the files?

The reason for this is, once the lambda has completed processing all the file, I would want to trigger a step function, so for me to trigger my Step Function I would want to do that only once all the files are processed by my lambda (XYZ).
FYI: There is no current way to track how many files have been uploaded

Comment: Can your Lambda function determine when the 'last' file has been processed? Are you able to modify the Lambda function source code itself, so that it could trigger the Step Function? Also, what does Java (in your title) have to do with the question?

Comment: Can your Lambda function determine when the 'last' file has been processed? - No
Are you able to modify the Lambda function source code itself, so that it could trigger the Step Function? - Yes I can modify the lambda code, but I don't want to run the step function for every file uplaod
Also, what does Java (in your title) have to do with the question? - Not relevant, I was trying to figure out if I can have a scheduler that keeps checking if an instance of lambda is running or not, so I mentioned that, it can be java, python or anything as such

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good design to run a step function state machine after the lambda completes the job without having a perfect logical event.

Because you can for example receive a bunch of files (say 100) completed by the lambda, **then using alarms with Cloudwatch once we complete the 100 values of a custom metric, or check value in DynamoDb or number of object in a custom folder**, fires a job step function, at the same time you receive another file with +5 sec delay to complete the 101, in this case maybe you miss this file.

If you don't have a special event or a condition to have the completion of the files, then you can work with time scheduling and trigger your Step function with Cloudwatch event ( scheduled event) like every 15 min, check if there is work if not, exit the job.

Otherwise, either include the lambda (file process) in your step function as a step or change your design.

Comment: Once all the files are processed by the lambda, we are running a data crawler and then running some glue jobs. So we can't trigger step function from the lambda or have that as the step itself

Comment: You can have trigger step function from rest api ( API Gateway) like post method, after your jobs are done